# Ruby On Rails using helper methods in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I've started using Ruby on Rails just a week ago and still fairly new so if anyone could help me out with this problem I would greatly appreciate it this is a personal project I'm working on not school work. So the problem is that I'm trying to click one of the anime images from my jcarousel on my html page and display its description in a separate div (id = content)in the p tag using helper methods listed below however its not working properly it always shows the last description of the anime's from my database can anyone help?

**My Helper Methods**

```
module HomepageHelper
attr_accessor :info
def getDescription(des)
   @info = des
end
def setDescription()
   content_tag(:p, @info)
end
end
```

**My HTML page**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>,
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media:"all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"%>
    <title>Anime Shuffle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Anime Shuffle</h1>

                <ul id="navigator">
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="video.html">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">List</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="ContentSearch">
            <ul id="search">

                <li><input type="text" name="query" value="Search"></input></a></li>
                <li><a href="home.html">Popular</a></li>
                <li><a href="videos.html">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="anime_list.html">Shuffle</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class='jcarousel'>

            <ul id='carousel_ul'>
                    <% @animes.each do |anime| %>
                        <li>
                            <%= link_to image_tag(anime.img_src,:data => {:description => anime.aname, :title => anime.aname}),'getDescription(anime.description)' %> 

                            <figcaption> 
                                <%= anime.aname %> 
                            </figcaption>

                        </li>

                    <% end %>


            </ul>
            <div id="left1" class="left"  data-jcarouselcontrol="true"><div class="arrow-left"> </div>  
            </div>
            <div id="right1"class="right" data-jcarouselcontrol="true"><div class="arrow-right"></div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="content">
                <div id="Rating">
                    <p>0.0</p>
                    <div id="episode-title">
                        <p>Episode List</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id= "episodes-list">
                        <li><p>Episode<p>1<p>-<p>Upload Date</p></p></p></li>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div id ="info">
                    <p>Synposis</p>
                    <div id = "info-content">
                        <p><%= setDescription %></p>
                        <div id="tags">
                            <li><p>Tags: <p>something, somthing, something, something</p></p></li>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="Review">
                    <p>Review</p>
                    <div id= "Review-content">
                        <p>Ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>



    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div id='footer-container'>
            <p>Powered by Net</p>
        </div>
    <div>

</body>
```

**javascript**

```
var id = "";

setInterval(function() {

    var left1 = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left'));

    if ($('#left1').is(":hover")) {
        $('#carousel_ul').css('left', left1+1.5);
        if(left1> 150)
        {
            $('#carousel_ul li:last').insertBefore($('#carousel_ul li:first'))
            $('#carousel_ul').css('left', 0);
        }
    }
     else if ($('#right1').is(":hover")) {
        $('#carousel_ul').css('left', left1-1.5);
        if(left1 < -150)
        {
            $('#carousel_ul li:first').insertAfter($('#carousel_ul li:last'))
            $('#carousel_ul').css('left', 0);
        }
    }
    },10);
    $(document).ready(function() {
       setInterval();
    });
```

Comment: Try to write Javascript for the link `onclick` and call `setdescription` method for each link dynamically

Comment: in your link_to seems like you are calling getDescription(anime.description) inside quotes. Is it really being called? I guess you must not use quotes!

Comment: I was messing around with it trying different things it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **@info** is an instance variable, so it's created once when the page loads. Now, because you have a loop to print the carousel, you repeatedly call the **'getDescription'** method, overriding each time the **@info** variable. When you finally try to use it's value with the **setDescription**, of course you get the last description.

The problem here is that you're generating one single **"content"** div at server-time with the last description. You should instead generate one for each anime (with a loop, like you did in the carousel), showing the correct one clicking the image.

Without the JavaScript code, is difficult to help you more than this.

**EDIT**

Ok, after some comments maybe I understood that you're a bit confused.
The problem here is that you're mixing client-side and server-side code.
**HomepageHelper** is a Rails helper, so that code just live on server-side, and you can't reference it from javascript, you can use it only to build the view.
So, first we will need to update the link_to tag in the carousel to make te link manage the **onclick** event:

```
link_to image_tag(anime.img_src,:data => {:description => anime.aname, :title => anime.aname}), '#',
    :onclick => 'setDetail("contentFor' + anime.id +  '")'
```

Where have added the **onclick** event to the carousel images, so if you click on them you will call the javascript function **setDetail** passing "contentForN" as argument, where N will vary based on the **anime id**.

Next step, let's implement this new javascript function (i'm assuming you're using jQuery):

```
var current = null;

var setDetail = function (divId) {
    if (current != null) {
        $("#"+current).css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#"+current).css("height", 0);
    }
    $("#"+divId).css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#"+divId).css("height", auto);
}
```

Finally, you have to print a **"content" div** for each anime:

```
<% @animes.each do |anime| %>
    <div id="contentFor<%= anime.id %>" class="content" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0">
            <div id="Rating">
                <p>0.0</p>
                <div id="episode-title">
                    <p>Episode List</p>
                </div>
                <div id= "episodes-list">
                    <li><p>Episode<p>1<p>-<p>Upload Date</p></p></p></li>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id ="info">
                <p>Synposis</p>
                <div id = "info-content">
                    <p><%= anime.description %></p>
                    <div id="tags">
                        <li><p>Tags: <p>something, somthing, something, something</p></p></li>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="Review">
                <p>Review</p>
                <div id= "Review-content">
                    <p>Ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This should work, and you don't need the helper anymore.
You should move the inline css inside your standard css.

Comment: Thanks! posted the Java script code above if you want to take a look

Comment: You don't have a function that manage the click in the carousel. The javascript you have posted seems to only set the Interval for the carousel, but not the onclick event... How do you think the description could change when you click on an image? I think you're a bit confused, let me some time to show a different approach, ok :)?

Comment: yeah sure...but to clarify I wasn't planning on using javascript at at tat point...I was thinking that I could use straight up helper methods to change everything...after a lot of researching I came to the conclusion to write a function for the click event on the image but I have no clue how to go about it

Comment: You can't use the helper function di modify the page once this has been printed in the browser, Server-side code (rails code) is executed BEFORE the page reaches the browser. I edite the answer, let me know if it works or if you have other problems :)

Comment: For the `link_to`, Is the formatting for `'setDetail("contentFor' + anime.id +  '")'` right?

Comment: Do you get any error? Take a look at the JS console if nothing happens

Comment: I copied everything like you wrote it no errors occur however, everything below the carousel disappears except the footer

Comment: Yeah is correct! It should appear once you click an image in the carousel! what happens when you click one of the images? Can you put a breakpoint in my JavaScript function to see if it gets triggered?

Comment: Glad it helped ;) please accept the answer so others can see it worked

Comment: hey man thanks for your help, your code was working however it only displayed the description only once so I had to redo your javascript code and finally got it to work thanks for steering me in the right direction :)